# Jquery UI Autocomplete : Uncaught TypeError: a(...).addClass(...).appendTo(...).menu is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

**Error Stack**

```
Uncaught TypeError: a(...).addClass(...).appendTo(...).menu is not a function
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/autocomplete.min.js:11:2166)
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._create (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js:11:1032)
at a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._createWidget (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js:11:3093)
at new a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js:11:593)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js:11:2365)
at Function.each (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:2881)
at n.fn.init.each (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:846)
at n.fn.init.a.fn.(anonymous function) [as autocomplete] (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/widget.min.js:11:2275)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/wordpress/?__pm_frame=1:195:29)
at i (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:27449)
```

**Script**

```
$('#email-request').autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo home_url( '/?task=findemails' ); ?>",
    minLength: 2,
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="email-request" type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Start typing to see suggestions" required/>
```

**Source Code**

to show they are added correctly :)

[image: Source code of added scripts]

**What I tried...**

I searched around. Found a few suggestions to include jquery-ui-menu as well and I did that but the error is persisting. Not sure what's causing this. Any help is appreciated :).

**Update....**

I tired console.log($.fn.menu);, return undefined. This returns undefined if menu is not included but as you can see in the screenshot menu is included. What could be causing this?

**Details of included Menu UI**

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI Menu 1.11.4
 * http://jqueryui.com
 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/
 */
```

Comment: Please be confirm that all required file added in properly. Also it will be better if you create a fiddle version with your code.

Comment: Yes it's added properly. I can add a screenshot of source code if you want.

Comment: I can't see the jquery library in your screen shot.

Comment: Yup but trust me on this, it's there. If it's not error stack will be different :D

Comment: Your question title and attached screen shot says it it jquery library absence problem. Because addClass(). appendTo() etc is method of jquery object. Please check carefully again.

Comment: Ok. For further clarification there are other codes that run before this snippet. They all works fine. No issues. So it's definitely not the absence of jQuery that's causing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166290/discussion-between-aravind-m-j-and-hanif).

Comment: Hello! If you've found answer, please, share it with us!